# Python xpath parsing return memory localization

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

Print return memory localization:
`<Element td at 0x3488120>`

```
from lxml import html
import requests


tritanium = 'https://evepraisal.com/item/34'
xpathtritanium = '//*[@id="jita"]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td'

pagetritanium = requests.get(tritanium)
print(pagetritanium.text)
parsing = html.fromstring(pagetritanium.text)
textvalue = parsing.xpath(xpathtritanium)

print(textvalue)
```

I expect result like: 6,95 ISK
(MIN sell order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textvalue` is list type object, try this to get the text value of td

```
print(textvalue[0].text)
```

**O/P:**

```
6.94 ISK
```

[`more details`](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method) how to work xpath.

Comment: I was slowly coming to that. I noticed that the type is a list. Thanks! All works. Now im study how to work xpath :)